# PHP Loop Does Not Iterate Over Every Row

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl, mysqli

I have written the following script: what it does is it goes to a webpage that outputs a JSON string, decodes the JSON string, and stores it's data in my database. The outermost `for` loop iterates over `$category` and the `foreach` loop immediately after iterates over `$alpha`, which is just an array of the entire alphabet +  `%23`, which is the number element. Every decoded JSON string, `$decoded->items`, contains multiple items, so there is an additional `foreach` loop inside to iterate over these items. When I try `echo $item->name` however, it only echoes the item names for *some* of the `$alpha` iterations.

I know that the problem is not the data itself, because every time I run it different items get echoed.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code (the database query portion is commented but it's besides the point, the error still remains):

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

$alphas = array("%23", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z");

function get_bool($string) {
    return ($string == "true") ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

$DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "drop_logger");

echo "<pre>";
for ($category = 0; $category <= 37; $category++) {
    foreach ($alphas as $alpha) {

        // Echoing the current category and alpha
        echo "category ".$category.", alpha ".$alpha." \n";         

        // Getting data
        $curl = curl_init();
        $post_url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=".$category."&alpha=".$alpha;
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        // Decoding the JSON data
        $decoded = json_decode($data);
        $decoded = $decoded->items;

        // Storing each new item into the database
        foreach ($decoded as $item) {
            echo $item->name."\n";/*
            $DB->query(
                "INSERT INTO GE_items (item_ID, item_name, item_icon, item_icon_large, item_type, item_type_icon, item_description, item_members)
                 VALUES ("
                    .$item->id.", '"
                    .$item->name."', '"
                    .$item->icon."', '"
                    .$item->icon_large."', '"
                    .$item->type."', '"
                    .$item->typeIcon."', '"
                    .$item->description."', "
                    .get_bool($item->members)
                 .")"
            );*/
        }

        @flush();
        @ob_flush();
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```

**EDIT:** Here's a sample of the output:

```
category 4, alpha y 
category 4, alpha z 
category 5, alpha %23 
category 5, alpha a 
category 5, alpha b 
category 5, alpha c 
category 5, alpha d 
category 5, alpha e 
category 5, alpha f 
category 5, alpha g 
category 5, alpha h 
category 5, alpha i 
category 5, alpha j 
category 5, alpha k 
category 5, alpha l 
category 5, alpha m 
category 5, alpha n 
category 5, alpha o 
Oak armchair
Oak armour case
Oak bed
Oak bench
Oak bookcase
Oak cape rack
Oak chair
Oak clock
Oak costume box
Oak dining table
Oak drawers
Oak dresser
category 5, alpha p 
category 5, alpha q 
category 5, alpha r 
category 5, alpha s 
category 5, alpha t 
category 5, alpha u 
category 5, alpha v 
category 5, alpha w 
category 5, alpha x 
category 5, alpha y 
category 5, alpha z 
category 6, alpha %23 
category 6, alpha a 
category 6, alpha b
```

**EDIT 2:** I checked the database table, and while scrolling I was presented with: `Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields. On submission, some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars configuration.` I'm not sure if this is related to the problem, however.

**EDIT 3:** I came across something interesting... I repeatedly ran the script for the same category, 35. Every single time it would return the exact same data set of 134 items. The category itself contains 164 items. I browsed the items under this category on the this page http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/catalogue?cat=35, and it seems as though the script is omitting 30 of these items (it's the same 30 items every time). I used `sleep()`, and I even changed the script to not iterate over `$alpha`s that have 0 items, and I keep getting the same 134 items...

For category 35, I checked the page linked above and compared the items listed there and the items that my script output. On http://pastebin.com/9Aj9AtWL, I posted a file of all 164 items; the ones marked with two asterisks before them were missing from my output. The pattern seems to be that after 12 items of the same `$alpha` (letter that they begin with), the rest of the items of that `$alpha` are omitted. I even tried other numbers for the category, and the pattern was the same: only the first 12 items per $alpha were output in my file...

Comment: It's hard to say without to have a dump from $decoded and the output from your loop... Maybe you want to walk recursively in $decoded ? If yes, your foreach will give you only the root elements...

Comment: When I ran the code it timed out.

Comment: The problem is that data structure received from server and stored in $data changes and different from data structure you are expecting. "Every decoded JSON string, $decoded->items, contains multiple items" - wring assumption.

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich I don't really understand, could you please explain a bit more? Edit: even if there is only one item in `$decoded->items`, it is still stored in an array.

Comment: Added Edit 3 @AlexanderRavikovich

Answer (score 0):

> Every decoded JSON string, $decoded->items, contains multiple items,
>   so there is an additional foreach loop inside to iterate over these
>   items.

Now, for example, look at sources of this two urls.

view-source:http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=5&alpha=o

and

view-source:http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=4&alpha=y

The first works as needed. But the second returns empty items.

```
{"total":15,"items":[]}
```

So, most of URLs return just empty array. Look:

view-source:http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=4&alpha=c
view-source:http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=4&alpha=d
view-source:http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=4&alpha=e
view-source:http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=4&alpha=h

**I figured out your problem!**

1. Add **set_time_limit(0);** to begining of your script.
2. Run your script, wait 10-20 seconds
3. Try open any URLs that I posted before. Just click on one of them. You will see blank page. OOOOPS! Your web-server gets down :)

The big problem is that server responds with blank page but with valid header status `200 OK`.

In fact that server isn't yours, the best solution for you is to use sleep(); - fo example, make connections once in 5 seconds, and hope that the server will live with that.

Try this. I also try here to reuse CURL connection. This is slow because sleep(); but this is the only way you can do it.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); // <--- SET NO TIME LIMIT
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

$alphas = array("%23", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z");

function get_bool($string) {
    return ($string == "true") ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

// Getting data
$curl = curl_init();

// Open the text file
$f = fopen("data.txt", "w");

for ($category = 0; $category <= 37; $category++) {
    foreach ($alphas as $alpha) {
        fwrite($f, "category ".$category.", alpha ".$alpha." \n");

        $post_url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=".$category."&alpha=".$alpha;
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Connection: Keep-Alive',
            'Keep-Alive: 300'
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($curl);

        // Decoding the JSON data
        $decoded = json_decode($data);
        $decoded = $decoded->items;

        // Storing each new item into the database
        foreach ($decoded as $item) {
            fwrite($f, $item->name."\n");
        }

        sleep(5);
    }
}

// Close the text file
fclose($f);

curl_close($curl);

echo "DONE";
?>
```

Comment: That's true, but I just ran the script a few times, and some of the times I got nothing output for `category 0, alpha e`, and other times I got `category 0, alpha e Elder energy Elysian sigil shard`, so the script seems to output different values each time I run it.

Comment: You should trace the $data variable... I guess your problem isn't in your code but in the service you are querying...

Comment: @mathieu That was a good idea. I output `var_dump($data)` for each iteration and that's where the problem lies. For example, for category 35 alpha g, `var_dump($data)` was `string(0) ""`, but navigating to that URL actually showed me that there were a lot of items for category 35 and alpha g. Any suggestions as to why `curl` isn't returning that data to me?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a Curl issue, your data source seems not to be stable. Maybe you reach the timeout sometimes...

Comment: I figured out your problem!

Comment: ... or you are throttled back because you spam it too much... Something like this...

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich Do you know how I can prevent the server from going down?

Comment: The server isn't mine. My script is running on localhost and the webpage I'm accessing is an API made and hosted by runescape.com, so I don't have access to these logs. (information about the API http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Grand_Exchange_APIs)

Answer (score 0):

The api is documented here:
http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Grand_Exchange_APIs

I guess you call the server too much, that's why it is ignoring you after a few calls.

First i would improve my code to ask for available letters for a given category with a query like that:

http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/category.json?category=1

It'll give you all the available letters for this category. This way you'll not do unsuccessful queries for letters which aren't available. (and spam the server less).

If it's not enough, you can try to use sleep() in your code to slow down your requests.

Comment: And i would add an "if" in my code to test blank answers from the server and stop the script execution if it occurs. (no need to continue if the server is already ignoring you)